# How is Lambic fruit beer traditionally made?

Tags: lambic

There are a few fruit beers around how are these traditionally made?  I know they are all Lambics, but how are they made exactly?

Comment: I think lambic fruit beers are not part of any tradition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lambic is a type of beer brewed in the Pajottenland region of Belgium and in Brussels itself at the Cantillon Brewery and museum. Lambic beer is produced by spontaneous fermentation: it is exposed to the wild yeasts and bacteria native to the Zenne valley. This gives the beer a dry, vinous, and cidery taste, usually with a sour aftertaste.

This beer forms the basis of the Lambic fruit beers. After the Lambic is made, fruit juice is added to the barrels right before bottleing the beer.

Comment: Or if you like the lambic process but aren't as keen on the fruit, look for "gueuze", which is the same process except they don't add the fruit juice at the end.

Comment: Although rephrased considerably, you might want to note that a fair bit of this answer was taken from Wikipedia.